# Is there any windows container guide for puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to use `PuppeteerSharp` with .NET Core3.1 in a windows container, is there some necessary dependencies for using `puppeteer` in windows container?

When I use `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64` image, seemed there's some dependencies missing, when I use `mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004-amd64`, it works, but this image is too large.

Is there some guide for using windows container? Some necessary dependencies for windows container?